# Intermittent SQL Server Connection Issues in .NET Core Application on Kubernetes (k8s)

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, .net-core

I have an application developed in .NET Core running on a Kubernetes (k8s) cluster. This application connects to an SQL Server. Lately, I've been experiencing an issue where, at certain times during the day, for a few seconds each time, the application loses its connection to the SQL Server. During these moments, the health check from the pod to a series of SQL Server instances shows them as unavailable (around 30 servers). The primary error messages I encounter are as follows:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
> ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): Unknown error 258

My application uses the Dapper library for database connectivity. I have reviewed the code, and all connections are opened and closed properly (late opening, early closing). The connection string I use only includes basic information: server, database, username, and password information, with no specific settings for the connection pool (considered as default).

I've also monitored one of the SQL Server instances in the 'Activity Monitor' under 'Processes,' and I see an average of approximately 1000 processes during these times.

I'm seeking advice and guidance from the community on how to investigate and determine the root cause of this issue. Any suggestions, insights, or experiences from those who have dealt with similar problems would be greatly appreciated. My expectation is to identify the underlying cause of these intermittent connection problems and find a solution to prevent them from occurring in the future.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Hi Thế Vinh, I don't have a direct answer to identify the issue in your situation. But what I reccomend you is to implement some retry technique to make your system more relience, specifically you could try to use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) library. 
Note that  timeout could occurr also in case of locks due to other statements running on same resources.

Comment: Hi Roberto Ferraris, thank you for your advice. I have applied retry to ensure the system can still respond to customers without interruption. But I still want to thoroughly handle the above problem. Thank you very much.